# SMTP configuration SendUsing configuration value is invalid with ASP-Classic

Tags: asp-classic, email

I'm trying to get an email sent using ASP classic, and am having trouble with SMTP configuration.

The error:

> CDO.Message.1 error '80040220' The "SendUsing" configuration value is
>   invalid.

The Code(for the email itself):

```
Set objMsg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")  
objMsg.From     = "name@name.com"  
objMsg.To       = "themetatron@gmail.com"  
objMsg.Subject  = "Procurement Ally Update"  
objMsg.TextBody = strBody
```

The Code I tried to configure with (pt 1):

```
sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"  
Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")   
    With cdoConfig.Fields   
        .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = "127.0.0.1"   
        .update   
    End With
```

That didn't work, so I tried:

```
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"  
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25  
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Update
```

That also didn't work.

(Yes, I didn't show it, but at the end there's a call to `objMsg.Send`)

As far as I can tell, the local boxes SMTP service is running and ready to do its duty.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If anyone found this page wondering how to send an email from Excel using CDO, I threw together a Google Doc [How to Send Email from Excel using Gmail](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u5VLzCApU3k4-9Vp9LEfqyFZ6u9tAY0avNPYN_1FsN4/edit?usp=sharing) with [code on GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/bergerjac/7355d4e528fa6c64a02dc494f3d241a1)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are specifying an smptserver, be sure to set your '[sendusing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms873037(EXCHG.65).aspx)' field to 2 (or cdoSendUsingPort) as well:

```
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Update
```

Answer (score 1):

As the SMTP service is on the localhost it makes more sense to send to pickup directory using SendUsingPickup (1). This will be more efficient than sending over network to port 25.

```
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 1
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverpickupdirectory") = "C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup"
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Update
```

Comment: both corbin march and this worked.  I like this one if you've got a smtp pickup location.  note, the 'update' line is critical.  You'll keep getting the error until you update.