# Mail going in Bad mail folder

Tags: asp-classic, smtp

I wrote an auto mail program for sending mails using asp

```
Sub MailSend(fromWho,toWho,Subject,MailBodyContent,CC,BCC)
SET myMail=Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    myMail.From=fromWho
    myMail.To=toWho
    myMail.Subject=Subject
    myMail.Cc=CC
    myMail.BCC=BCC
    myMail.textbody=MailBodyContent
    myMail.htmlbody=MailBodyContent
    myMail.Send
SET myMail=Nothing 
End  Sub
```

Now the problem is the mail is going to the Bad Mail repeatedly and it shown an error message.

"The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your service provider instead."

I got a solution for this through this link http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/ but still the mails are going in the Bad Mail folder. Please help

Comment: Not an answer to your problem *per se*, but if you send two identical parts and call one `text/plain` and the other `text/html`, in my humble opinion, you deserve to be filtered.

Comment: Are you using that code on your production webserver, or is it on a development server on your own computer.  If the latter is true then the problem might go away when you upload it.  This question may be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582756/smtp-configuration-sendusing-configuration-value-is-invalid-with-asp-classic

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You are setting up the mail body content twice with myMail.textbody and myMail.htmlbody. If your message content is not html, remove the myMail.htmlbody line. If your content is HTML, remove the myMail.textbody line.
2. The error message is telling you the problem: you cannot send to that mail server from your server's IP address (using standard SMTP I am assuming). Maybe you need to use a different SMTP server or use a secure authentication method with credentials to converse with that mail server.