# Classic ASP CDO.Message SMTP setup

Tags: asp-classic, smtp, office365, cdo.message

A client of ours migrated a Classic ASP application to Windows Server 2012 and pages that send email stopped working. They would like to start sending email via a remote office365 host.  Do they need to have SMTP set up on their own server in order to use CDO.Message to send mail through a remote host?

Thank you

Comment: The simple answer to your question is no they wouldn't. See the remote server configuration here. http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/sending_email_asp.php . Note that you need to use port 25 for smtp if you're using CDO with office365, it doesn't like 587.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a bit more @John? We are getting the error that "The 'SendUsing' configuration value is invalid." However, we are setting Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 as most people suggest for that error. The only other solution I say is people hinting that SMTP might be the issue

Comment: That should work, unless there are specific issues regarding the security settings of your server - see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582756/smtp-configuration-sendusing-configuration-value-is-invalid-with-asp-classic

Comment: We are already following the steps outlined in the question you linked, @John, by setting our  'sendusing' field to 2 (along with the other fields).