# ASP - CDO Email Configuration Issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8.5, cdo.message

I have a legacy `ASP` application that I moved from a old server to `Windows 2012` server with `IIS 8.5`.

I see the email sending is failing with the below error in IIS logs.

> 80040220|The__SendUsing__configuration_value_is_invalid

Current code is

```
Dim MyCDONTSMail2
Dim HTML
Set MyCDONTSMail2 = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
HTML = "all html format of mail content"
MyCDONTSMail2.From= "some from address"
MyCDONTSMail2.To="some to address"
MyCDONTSMail2.Subject="My Subject"
MyCDONTSMail2.HTMLBody=HTML
MyCDONTSMail2.Send
set MyCDONTSMail2=nothing
```

I have read a few other articles over Internet and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582756/smtp-configuration-sendusing-configuration-value-is-invalid-with-asp-classic) as well.  I add a little bit of configuration in the code as shown in all other articles

```
MyCDONTSMail2.HTMLBody=HTML
MyCDONTSMail2.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
MyCDONTSMail2.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="SMTP Server Name"
MyCDONTSMail2.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
MyCDONTSMail2.Configuration.Fields.Update
MyCDONTSMail2.Send
set MyCDONTSMail2=nothing
```

But I still get the same error.  My `SMTP Server Name` is absolutely correct as I used the same server in my other .Net applications hosted on the same server to this `ASP` application.  The .Net app works well with the same configuration.

I'm not sure if ASP pages need any other configuration / installation required.

I have also tried to configure my SMTP server inside the `IIS Website --> SMTL E-mail` and changing the smtp server in the `ASP` code to `localhost`.  But, it also resulted in the same error.

EDIT: `Application Pool` is set to `Classic Pipeline Mode` and `Identity` as `NetworkService`

Answer (score 0):

Your provided sample code is not SMTP Authenticated...please try to use SMTP Authenticated script..

.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "mail@yourdomain.com"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "email account password"

After that, have a check with email delivery.

Comment: Authentication depends on the SMTP setup; for ex: If I have to use `gmail` to send emails, I will have to provide user name, password etc...